# <.Chart.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}

Tags: kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm, configmap

When you deploy the chart you get the following error:
<.Chart.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a beginner mistake, fields start with upper case even though Chart.yaml field starts with lower case. Same with Chart.Version and all the other fields.

Very weird for java developers.

Comment: note: you can define your own fields which can be both lower or upper case

Comment: I ran into the same issue trying to reference `.Chart.appVersion` instead of `.Chart.AppVersion`

Answer (score 0):

As per [official helm documentation](https://helm.sh/) there are terms [Predefined Values](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#predefined-values) and [Built-in Objects](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/)

> The built-in values always begin with a capital letter. This is in
>   keeping with Go’s naming convention. When you create your own names,
>   you are free to use a convention that suits your team

List of those mandatory capitalized built-in values

- `Release`: This object describes the release itself. It has several objects inside of it:

  - `Release.Name`: The release name
  - `Release.Namespace`: The namespace to be released into (if the manifest doesn’t override)
  - `Release.IsUpgrade`: This is set to  `true`  if the current operation is an upgrade or rollback.
  - `Release.IsInstall`: This is set to  `true`  if the current operation is an install.
  - `Release.Revision`: The revision number for this release. On install, this is 1, and it is incremented with each upgrade and rollback.
  - `Release.Service`: The service that is rendering the present template. On Helm, this is always  `Helm`.
- `Values`: Values passed into the template from the  `values.yaml`  file and from user-supplied files. By default,  `Values`  is empty.
- `Chart`: The contents of the  `Chart.yaml`  file. Any data in  `Chart.yaml`  will be accessible here. For example  `{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}`  will print out the  `mychart-0.1.0`.

  - The available fields are listed in the  [Charts Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file)
- `Files`: This provides access to all non-special files in a chart. While you cannot use it to access templates, you can use it to access other files in the chart. See the section  *Accessing Files*  for more.

  - `Files.Get`  is a function for getting a file by name (`.Files.Get config.ini`)
  - `Files.GetBytes`  is a function for getting the contents of a file as an array of bytes instead of as a string. This is useful for things like images.
  - `Files.Glob`  is a function that returns a list of files whose names match the given shell glob pattern.
  - `Files.Lines`  is a function that reads a file line-by-line. This is useful for iterating over each line in a file.
  - `Files.AsSecrets`  is a function that returns the file bodies as Base 64 encoded strings.
  - `Files.AsConfig`  is a function that returns file bodies as a YAML map.
- `Capabilities`: This provides information about what capabilities the Kubernetes cluster supports.

  - `Capabilities.APIVersions`  is a set of versions.
  - `Capabilities.APIVersions.Has $version`  indicates whether a version (e.g.,  `batch/v1`) or resource (e.g.,  `apps/v1/Deployment`) is available on the cluster.
  - `Capabilities.KubeVersion`  and  `Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version`  is the Kubernetes version.
  - `Capabilities.KubeVersion.Major`  is the Kubernetes major version.
  - `Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor`  is the Kubernetes minor version.
- `Template`: Contains information about the current template that is being executed

  - `Name`: A namespaced file path to the current template (e.g.  `mychart/templates/mytemplate.yaml`)
  - `BasePath`: The namespaced path to the templates directory of the current chart (e.g.  `mychart/templates`).

Small example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
spec:
type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
ports:
- port: {{ .Values.service.externalPort }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
    protocol: TCP
    name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
selector:
    app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
```

And again - feel free to use any other manually defined values with lower-case.
Hope it helps

Comment: this doesn't answer the question